# Regex match for HTML tag containing "on" JS trigger

Tags: regex

I want to check if an HTML tag (potentially split across multiple lines) contains an "on" JS trigger. The actual HTML tag and the Javascript are of no consequence.  For example:

```
    <img src="foo.jpg" onblur="foo()"/>Other stuff
```

I've got most of this to work using the pattern:

```
    <\w+([^>])+?(on\w+)+[\s\S]+?>
```

However, this also matches:

```
    <p style="font-size:11px;">Other stuff</p>
```

I modified the original pattern to:

```
    <\w+([^>])+?(\s)+(on\w+)+[\s\S]+?>
```

but this matches only if the JS trigger keyword is preceded by 2 or more whitespace characters.  A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: In what context are you doing this?  Why are you doing this?

Comment: And which regex tool are you using?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I want to filter potentially hazardous HTML.

Comment: @ridgerunner http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: [I don't care how old this question is, this is the only right answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4532996)

Comment: @cat I didn't want to parse HTML.  I just wanted to check for the presence of JS containing an "on" trigger.

Comment: Yes, you're trying to parse HTML, and you should use an HTML engine not regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might work `<\w+(?=\s)[^>]*?\s(on\w+)[\s\S]+?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
(?m)(?i).*(?=([^a-z]on)).*>
```

Try this will match the html if it contains an `on` but wont match it if it is mid word

Comment: The multi-line modifier won't let the last `.*`> span newlines (if it had to match > next).